# Permanent back button redirect

Tags: redirect

We recently had a developer update parts of our site. For some reason he has implemented a **permanent redirect** on our browser back button which goes to a specific landing page.

Does anyone know how to fix this. I've looked through lots of the files and can't see any code that relates to the browser back button.

Unfortunately we can't contact the previous developer so we are trying to figure this out ourselves. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is this a Magento related issue?
You need to provide more information to help people understand what this is about

Comment: Too little information. We can't see anything from here. At least give us a link. Probably you need to let another developer have a look.

Comment: Hi, sorry yes it's all magento. We are using 1.7 at the moment, our website is www.bragvintage.co.uk. If you navigate to any other page and then click the browser back button you will see that you are always redirected to the womens landing page instead of the previous page. We would like to remove this redirect so that the back button functions as normal. Thanks in advance for your help.